# Virtual Host in XAMPP (help)

Tags: 14.04, permissions, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

İ want to create the Virtual Host in XAMPP. Thus I googled for it. and  I did the same changes in my config files like as [Virtual Host in XAMPP](http://septiadi.com/2012/05/04/add-new-virtual-host-xampp-or-lampp-on-linux/). But when I went `http://localhost2` it say's me:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>
> localhost2
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

I also googled for this problem. but nothing could help me.

here is my ["/etc/hosts" and "virtual host" configuration files](http://1drv.ms/1iNtEoZ)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you have a index.html in /home/mirjalal/localhost2 ?

Comment: Have you gone and also checked your error logs to see what exactly's being reported along with the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apache documentation, ServerName requires an [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). localhost name is not a Fully qualified domain name.

I suggest to change your vhost configuration:

```
      <VirtualHost *:80>
          DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs
          ServerName firstSite.localhost
          ServerAlias www.firstSite.localhost
      </VirtualHost> 

      <VirtualHost *:80>
          DocumentRoot /home/mirjalal/localhost2
          ServerName secondSite.localhost
          ServerAlias www.secondSite.localhost 
          <Directory "/home/mirjalal/localhost2">
                 Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks
                 AllowOverride All
                 Require all granted
          </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>
```

Where **VirtualHost** *:80 means that apache listen on any IP address, port 80 and that you are defining "[Name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)".
**ServerName** now are FQDN consists of two parts: the hostname and the domain name.
**DocumentRoot** sets the directory from which httpd will serve files.

I add **Directory** directive because I guess main server (defined in apache2.conf) doesn't do that for your /home/mirjalal/localhost2 directory.

Save this directive in /etc/apache2/sites-available/myWebSite.conf

Open your /etc/hosts and change hostname:

```
      127.0.0.1 localhost
      127.0.1.1 mirjalal-PC
      127.0.0.1 firstSite.localhost
      127.0.0.1 secondSite.localhost
```

Now we are ready to [start new site and stop default vhosts](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/a2dissite.8.html) listen on localhost:

```
      a2ensite myWebSite
      a2dissite 000-default
      service apache2 reload
```

In order to verify put a simple file index.html in /home/mirjalal/localhost2 and try `http://secondSite.localhost/`

Comment: big thanks for following and answering the question. but i couldn't did it. thus, it's not working for me..

Comment: what went wrong, are you still in trouble?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ could you explain your comment, please? Your good answer is relative to windows and it seems similar to mine except for contest, here is about ubuntu. Could you please tell me if in my answer there is something wrong?

Comment: @lety First of all I have not down voted your answer there got my upvote. Secondly I honestly don't remember why I wrote that comments. Therefore I will remove it. It might be irrelevant.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ it was not for the down vote, but it was to find out if you had any advice to improve my answer, I am re-checking my answers and I saw your comment that I had not noticed before. thanks anyway for your upvote.